# data:application/vnd.ms-excel how to change typeface

Tags: javascript, excel

I use data:application/vnd.ms-excel to make excel,but when I use it ,the typeface is always be Arial Unicode MS ,I want to change to other typeface,how can i do?

```
        var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=UTF-8;base64,',
        base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))); },
```

Comment: you'll need to edit the content of the spreadsheet

Comment: I see my data in jsp,they are in right type face,but when i excel it by this function,the excel i have become Arial Unicode MS,i want to change it when i export it into excel

Comment: Just creating a data URL won't change the fonts used in the spreadsheet data. There's something else going on here.

Comment: i think perhaps somthing i do not set,so the typeface show me in default，but i do not konw how to set it

Comment: so, you have excel that has the right typeface, but when you *export it into excel* it's the wrong typeface - how do you export excel into excel? I think you're not showing nearly enough code to understand what you're doing completely wrong